# How to store each individual IP adderss from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get a list of IP addresses of all connecting visitors to my website. I know I can get an ip address by using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but it always shows me only my IP address, if someone another connects to the website, it shows only their ip address to them. So I decided to make a database where I will store each individual value, but I dont know how to loop through to get all individual ip address. I am a bit confused.

Comment: The php reference manual states that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contains The IP address from which the user is viewing the current page. So you can store it in a db. Refer http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

Consider this script which you already have..

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Assume... When you put this script on your site say `http://yourwebsite.com/ip.php`  , When you access it .. it prints some `129.X.X.X` (which is your IP) , when somebody accesses it , It will show their IP say .. `80.X.X.X`

---

### To write it to a file..  You could do this..

```
<?php
file_put_contents('visitorsip.txt',echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],FILE_APPEND);
```

### To insert into a database.. You can write a query like

```
<?php

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
//do all your db connections..
$sql = 'INSERT INTO iptable (name) VALUES (?)';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array($ip));
$dbh->commit();
```

### Looping through...

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name FROM iptable");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(); //This $result array holds all your IP Addresses

//Lets loop..

foreach($result as $ips)
{
echo $ips."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a table to keep ip's and counts. Might want to include a isSpider and which spider. Something like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `ip_counts` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ip` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `isSpider` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `spider` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `ip` (`ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And for each visitor insert:

```
        INSERT INTO ip_counts SET ip='".$ip."', count=1, isSpider=".$isSpider.", spider='".$spider."' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1
```

Answer (score 0):

IP of login user can be fetched from: 
`httpcontext.Request.UserHostAddress`